# Nested recursion, find all possible piece counts

Tags: javascript, recursion, permutation

Given an example input:

```
[
    {"id":1,"currentBlack":1,"currentWhite":0,"max":1},
    {"id":2,"currentBlack":0,"currentWhite":1,"max":1},
]
```

Output all possible states of the input where currentBlack and currentWhite can have a value anywhere in the range from their initial value up to the maximum value.

Correct output for this example:

```
[
    [
        {"id":1,"currentBlack":1,"currentWhite":0,"max":1},
        {"id":2,"currentBlack":0,"currentWhite":1,"max":1},
    ],
    [
        {"id":1,"currentBlack":1,"currentWhite":1,"max":1},
        {"id":2,"currentBlack":0,"currentWhite":1,"max":1},
    ],
    [
        {"id":1,"currentBlack":1,"currentWhite":1,"max":1},
        {"id":2,"currentBlack":1,"currentWhite":1,"max":1},
    ],
    [
        {"id":1,"currentBlack":1,"currentWhite":0,"max":1},
        {"id":2,"currentBlack":1,"currentWhite":1,"max":1},
    ]
]
```

The real input will have max anywhere between 1 and 8 and there will be far more objects within the input array. My attempt is below (heavily commented):

```
function allPossibleCounts(pieceCounts) {//pieceCounts is the input
        var collection = []; //used to collect all possible values
        recursiveCalls(pieceCounts); //runs recursive function
        return collection; //returns result

        function recursiveCalls(pieceCounts) {
            //if pieceCounts is already in collection then return, not yet implemented so duplicates are currently possible
            collection.push(pieceCounts);//inputs a potential value

            console.log(JSON.stringify(pieceCounts));//this is successfully logs the correct values
            console.log(JSON.stringify(collection));//collection isn't correct, all values at the top of the array are copies of each other

            for (let n in pieceCounts) {//pieceCounts should be the same at the start of each loop within each scope, aka pieceCounts should be the same at the end of this loop as it is at the start

                subBlackCall(pieceCounts);
                function subBlackCall(pieceCounts) {
                    if (pieceCounts[n].currentBlack < pieceCounts[n].max) {
                        pieceCounts[n].currentBlack++;//increment
                        recursiveCalls(pieceCounts);
                        subBlackCall(pieceCounts);//essentially you're either adding +1 or +2 or +3 ect all the way up to max and calling recursiveCalls() off of each of those incremented values
                        pieceCounts[n].currentBlack--;//decrement to return pieceCounts to how it was at the start of this function
                    }
                }

                subWhiteCall(pieceCounts);
                function subWhiteCall(pieceCounts) {
                    if (pieceCounts[n].currentWhite < pieceCounts[n].max) {
                        pieceCounts[n].currentWhite++;
                        recursiveCalls(pieceCounts);
                        subWhiteCall(pieceCounts);
                        pieceCounts[n].currentWhite--;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But currently my attempt outputs as this ungodly mess of copied arrays

```
[[{"id":1,"currentBlack":1,"currentWhite":1,"max":1},{"id":2,"currentBlack":1,"currentWhite":1,"max":1}],[{"id":1,"currentBlack":1,"currentWhite":1,"max":1},{"id":2,"currentBlack":1,"currentWhite":1,"max":1}],[{"id":1,"currentBlack":1,"currentWhite":1,"max":1},{"id":2,"currentBlack":1,"currentWhite":1,"max":1}],[{"id":1,"currentBlack":1,"currentWhite":1,"max":1},{"id":2,"currentBlack":1,"currentWhite":1,"max":1}],[{"id":1,"currentBlack":1,"currentWhite":1,"max":1},{"id":2,"currentBlack":1,"currentWhite":1,"max":1}]]
```

Edit: working code: https://pastebin.com/qqFTppsY

Comment: The ```pieceCounts[n]``` always reference to the one object. You should recreate the ```pieceCount``` for saving in to the collection as different object. For example, you can add ```pieceCounts = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(pieceCounts)); // just clone``` at the start of ```recursiveCalls``` function.

Comment: I figured it was a pointer issue, I couldn't understand why using .slice() never worked, just figured out a second ago it's because although it's copying the array the pointers to the objects within the array are all still the same. You should put this as an answer though, it's correct

Comment: Why can you not have the combination of id: 1, currentBlack: 0, currentWhite: 0?

Comment: Because the initial input sets the lower bound, that way you can recursively go through it more easily and not have to have a min: value in the object. The whole program is calculating the number of legal ways a chess board of dimensions x,y can be set up. This was the final piece in the puzzle, it generates all of the possible combinations for number of pieces on the board. The reason zero isn't necessarily the minimum bound for my particular program is that you must always have 1 black and 1 white king for the board to be legal. There are other restrictions as well, but that one applies here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pieceCounts[n]` always reference to the one object. You should recreate the `pieceCount` for saving in to the collection as different object. For example, you can add

```
pieceCounts = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(pieceCounts)); // just clone
```

at the start of `recursiveCalls` function.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid conversion to JSON and back, I would suggest using `Object.assign` to perform a deeper copy in combination with `map` on the array:

```js
function allPossibleCounts(pieceCounts) {
    var result = [],
        current = deeperCopy(pieceCounts);

    function deeperCopy(arr) {
        return arr.map( row => Object.assign({}, row) );
    }

    function recurse(depth) {
        // depth: indication of which value will be incremented. Each "row" has 
        // 2 items (black/white), so when depth is even, it refers to black, when 
        // odd to white. Divide by two for getting the "row" in which the increment
        // should happen.
        var idx = depth >> 1, // divide by 2 for getting row index
            prop = depth % 2 ? 'currentWhite' : 'currentBlack', // odd/even
            row = pieceCounts[idx];
        if (!row) { // at the end of the array
            // Take a copy of this variation and add it to the results
            result.push(deeperCopy(current));
            return; // backtrack for other variations
        }
        for (var value = row[prop]; value <= row.max; value++) {
            // Set the value of this property
            current[idx][prop] = value;
            // Collect all variations that can be made by varying any of 
            //   the property values that follow after this one
            recurse(depth+1);
            // Repeat for all higher values this property can get.
        }
    }

    recurse(0); // Start the process
    return result;
}

// Sample input
var pieceCounts = [
    {"id":1,"currentBlack":1,"currentWhite":0,"max":1},
    {"id":2,"currentBlack":0,"currentWhite":1,"max":1},
];
// Get results
var result = allPossibleCounts(pieceCounts);
// Output
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

The idea is to use recursion: imagine the problem can be solved for all variations that can be made for all properties, except the first one. Produce those, and then change the first property value to the next possible value. Repeat again the production of all variations, etc. The combination of all those results together will be the solution for when the first property value should also be varied.

This is an ideal situation for recursion. The recursion stops when there are no more property values remaining: in that case there is only one solution; the one with all the values set as they are. It can be added to the list of results.

The properties can be enumerated like this:

```
row  currentBlack   currentWhite
---------------------------------
 0       0               1
 1       2               3
 2       4               5
 3       6               7
                ...
 n      2n-2            2n-1
```

We could call that number *depth*, and increase it at every step of deeper recursion. Given a depth, the property to vary is defined by:

```
depth is even  => currentBlack
depth is odd   => currentWhite
row number = depth / 2 (ignoring the remainder)
```

Comment: How efficient or inefficient is converting to JSON and back in comparison to using object.assign with map?

Comment: Thanks! That's really helpful, the difference in speed seems to vary lots though

Comment: Time used also depends on other things your browser and device is doing, but on average I see in Chrome the JSON-way is 15% slower, and on Firefox the difference is 200% or more. Here is the same fiddle, but running 10x longer: https://jsfiddle.net/4dac4pf5/1/

Comment: I'm running my code in node.js at the moment. By the way, using the real data as an input into my recursive function seems to have created an array that goes into the tens of millions (it's still going). This is simply because duplicate results of pieceCounts are so common with the way I've coded it so far. Have you got any ideas as to how I can make it better? I've edited into my post the function as I currently have it

Comment: I guess this becomes an X-Y problem. You can precalculate how many combinations you should get by multiplying all possibilities each property can have with eachother. So in your simple example that would be 1x2x2x1. You can easily see that this quickly gets out of hand with larger inputs. But I wonder what use all these millions of data will be to you?

Comment: Created a program which calculates all possible legal states of a chess board. Input the dimensions of the board, get out a number. I don't expect it to work on anything bigger than 4x4. But currently it doesn't work because this specific function causes javascript out of memory error, due to the stupid amount of repeat data generated

Comment: NB: most of the time will be spent in your removeDuplicates function.

Comment: I've gone back to using if already in collection array return, it's far more efficient. I'll tell you if it errors this time or not aha. Here's the real input for this particular function: 

[
    {"id":1,"currentBlack":0,"currentWhite":0,"max":2},
    {"id":2,"currentBlack":1,"currentWhite":1,"max":1},
    {"id":3,"currentBlack":0,"currentWhite":0,"max":1},
    {"id":4,"currentBlack":0,"currentWhite":0,"max":2},
    {"id":5,"currentBlack":0,"currentWhite":0,"max":2},
    {"id":6,"currentBlack":0,"currentWhite":0,"max":2}
]

That one is for a 2 wide 3 high chess board

Comment: So that has 3x3 x 1x1 x 2x2 x 3x3 x 3x3 x 3x3 = 9x1x4x9x9x9 = 26244 possibilities. I ran my code on that data, and it produces that array length in about half a second on my laptop.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: Hey @trincot, would you be able to comment your code? I'm just trying to wrap my head around it and figure out why it's so much faster than my current function, mainly confused by the >> bit shift and the alternating between black and white based on the depth

Comment: Ok don't worry I see why, because you're running through each row of pieceCounts and then you don't allow it to "backtrack" and add to currentWhite or currentBlack on a row that it's already produced all possible values for. While mine doesn't have idx so it just runs through all rows every time. Your solution is so neat it's unreal

Comment: I added an explanation any way.